# Is calling myself as Sunni or Shia considered sectarian?

Tags: sects

In the name of Allah,

As we know that Allah warns people that make sect as already stated in Surah Al-An'am (6:159)

> Translation: Sahih International
>
> Indeed, those who have divided their religion and become sects - you, [O Muhammad], are not [associated] with them in anything. Their affair is only [left] to Allah ; then He will inform them about what they used to do.

If I call myself as Sunni or Shia, do I fall under the words `become sect` in that Ayat?

Comment: If people ask just say you are a Muslim and you follow the teachings of Sunni but you are a Muslim and that’s that

Answer (score 1):

Being part of a group is not itself condemned. What is condemned is to be a part of a group that split away from what Allah commanded.

Whichever of the Sunnis or Shias go away from Allah's religion as in the Quran and Sunnah, you should not be part of them.

The verses that talk about sects are, in essence, about those who split away from the group of Allah.

Allah say criticizing those who split away from the truth into factions:

> But the people divided their religion among them into sects - each faction, in what it has, rejoicing. (23:53)

Allah affirms that one faction (His own faction on the truth) is correct:

> And whoever is an ally of Allah and His Messenger and those who have believed - indeed, the faction of Allah - they will be the predominant. (5:56)

The rest are factions of misguidance:

> Satan has overcome them and made them forget the remembrance of Allah. Those are the faction of Satan. Unquestionably, the faction of Satan - they will be the losers. (58:19)

Allah tells people not to go away from the central religion of Allah:

> And hold firmly to the rope of Allah all together and do not become divided. (3:103)

Some people of no knowledge misunderstand the verses and think no groups are allowed at all, neither Sunni nor Shia. That is both baseless and illogical.

There must obviously be one faction or group on the truth. Also note that no verse in the Quran forbids people from calling their faction different names, as long as they adhere to the truth.

So, people who claim calling oneself Sunni is not allowed have no evidence for their claims.

Answer (score 0):

‎السلام عليكم

‎اشهد أن لا اله الا الله محمد رسول الله
I bear witness that there is no god what day of worship expect Allah and muhammed is the last and final prophet of god. May God peace and blessings of god be upon the prophet and his family and friends and my Allah protect the nation of the prophet peace and blessings him.

We have to come to a understanding about the Shias first, according to the scholars of Islam, they aren’t part of Islam thus calling yourself shia isn’t permissible. It’s forbidden for a Muslim to call themself a Shias.

Sheikh ibn hazm said “Shias aren’t not even Muslims themselves” he said this when he was debating a Christian.

Imam malik and he’s student both affirm that Shias aren’t Muslim.

Sheikh Ibn Taymiya takfired the Shias and he also said they aren’t Muslims.

So a person who calls himself a Shia isn’t Muslim and this is forbidden.

As for Sunni part. We know that sunni Islam isn’t a sect anyone who says it is, is wrong.
Sunni is a person who follows the sunnah of the prophet. And according to the hadith
Of صحيح ابن حبان the prophet ‎صلى الله عليه وسلم said:

‎عَنْ عَبْدِ اللَّهِ بْنِ عَمْرٍو قَالَ قَالَ رَسُولُ اللَّهِ صَلَّى اللَّهُ عَلَيْهِ وَسَلَّمَ مَنْ رَغِبَ عَنْ سُنَّتِي فَلَيْسَ مِنِّي

“Whoever does not follow my Sunnah is not a part of me.” So just by this we know that we can call our selves Sunnis. Because it just means to follow the sunnah of the prophet.

Source: ‎صحيح ابن حبان الرقم 317
https://dorar.net/hadith/sharh/15777

Matter fact
Shaykh al-Islam Ibn Taymiyah (may Allah have mercy on him) said:

There is no shame in declaring oneself to be a follower of the salaf, belonging to it and feeling proud of it; rather that must be accepted from him, according to scholarly consensus. The madhhab of the salaf cannot be anything but true. If a person adheres to it inwardly and outwardly, then he is like the believer who is following truth inwardly and outwardly. If he adheres to it outwardly only, and not inwardly, then he is like the hypocrite; he is to be accepted as he appears to be, and what is hidden in his heart is left to Allah (to judge), because we are not instructed to check on what is in people’s hearts.

Source: مجموع الفتاوى 1/149

You can call yourself sunni,Muslim,salafi,ahulu sunnah,ahlu hadith all of these things that show that you are a believer you can call yourself this. This is permissible according to the opinion of all scholars of Islam. Sheikh Al-Albani Shaykh al-Islam Ibn Taymiyah and May more affirm this belife.

Inshallah I hope this helped.
‎السلام عليكم

Answer (score -1):

السلام علیکم

In any religion there are somebody who try to destroy the trueness.

This was very bold in Jewish and Christian people. Their religion absolutely destroyed and this is why we don't accept them. They don't believe in their true religious. This is called **Tahrif**.

This is also happened in Islam (Unfortunately). The Muhammad (PBUH) many times said the Ali (PBUH) is your Imam after me. Even in Qur'an:

> Today the disbelievers have given up all hope of ˹undermining˺ your faith. So do not fear them; fear Me! Today I have perfected your faith for you, completed My favour upon you, and chosen Islam as your way. (**Al-Qur'an, 5:3**)

About this verse, all of Religious scholars are sure Allah said this in **Ghadir Khom** area, where The Muhammad (PBUH) said all Muslims:

> مَن کُنْتُ مَولاهُ فَهٰذا **عَليٌّ** مَولاه

(Means "Whoever I was his master, [Since now] **Ali** (PBUH) is his master")

This hadith is as famous as we don't need to say any document to proof that. Every Shia or Sunni accept this hadith.

Or somewhere else The prophet Muhammad (PBUH) said:

> إنّي تٰارِکٌ فِيکُمُ الثَّقَلَيْن: **کِتابَ اللّٰه** وَ **عِتْرَتِي أهلُ بَیْتي**؛ إِنَّهُمَا **لَنْ يَفْتَرِقَا** حَتَّى يَرِدَا عَلَيَّ اَلْحَوْضَ

(Means "I am leaving for you the two weighty things: **the Book of God** (Al-Qur'an) and **my family, my household**. They **will not separate** until they return to the basin [Al-Kouthar].")

This hadith is also in the both Sunni books (like Sahih Al-Bukhari | Hadith No:6378) and Shia books (like Vasael-Al-Shia | Vol.33, P.27)

And we know that Ali (PBUH) and his family are family of the Muhammad (PBUH):

> Allah only intends to keep ˹the causes of˺ evil away from you and purify you completely, O  members of the ˹Prophet’s˺ family! (**Al-Qur'an, 33:33**)

So we know that only people who have no faults are members of family of the prophet Muhammad (PBUH). Why must not to accept them as **Imam**?

Returning to your main question: Isn't **Shi'ism** kind of "sect" in Islam?

Actually, **No**!

The true religion is very clean and everybody know that people who don't accept trueness is trying to make "Sect" in their religion and in this case, trying to reject Shi'ism, is actually the same "Section" in Islam.

Many rulings in Islam have been changed by Sunni caliphs. such as "how to pray" or "rules of marriage", etc. They tried much to **Tahrif** Islam and we don't believe in them.

في امانِ اللّٰه